# CalendarFX in combination with JavaFX: Module javafx.controls not found

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am trying to use [CalendarFX](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/CalendarFX) as a gradle dependency in my JavaFX project with the [gradle javafx plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin), but I get the error that Module javafx.controls is nout found, while clearly specifying in the build.gradle file that it should use the `javafx.controls` module. My setup is this:

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName = "org.example.MainApp"

sourceCompatibility = 13

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.calendarfx:view:11.8.3'
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```

MainApp.java:

```
package org.example;

import com.calendarfx.model.Calendar;
import com.calendarfx.model.CalendarSource;
import com.calendarfx.view.CalendarView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView();

        Calendar test = new Calendar("Test");
        test.setShortName("T");
        test.setStyle(Calendar.Style.STYLE1);

        CalendarSource familyCalendarSource = new CalendarSource("Source");
        familyCalendarSource.getCalendars().add(test);

        calendarView.getCalendarSources().setAll(familyCalendarSource);
        calendarView.setRequestedTime(LocalTime.now());

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(calendarView);

        Thread updateTimeThread = new Thread("Calendar: Update Time Thread") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        calendarView.setToday(LocalDate.now());
                        calendarView.setTime(LocalTime.now());
                    });

                    try {
                        // update every 10 seconds
                        sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        updateTimeThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        updateTimeThread.setDaemon(true);
        updateTimeThread.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calendar");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(1300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(1000);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And the error I get when I try to run is:

```
$ ./gradlew run

> Task :run FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 738ms
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: Can you try `./gradlew clean --info run`? (You will see printed the full command line used to run the project).

Comment: Hi, I just ran the command with the following result: https://pastebin.com/c0c6X80q
I find this error really weird because in the full run command it displays the javafx.controls package, and after the command, it says "Module javafx.controls not found".

Comment: It might be related to the fact that CalendarFX depends on JavaFX 13.0.1, and you are using 13.0. Somehow the javafx.controls jar is moved from the module path to the classpath. Can you try `version="13.0.2"`, or even `version="14"`?

Comment: I tried both versions, bad luck unfortunately, still "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"

Comment: Can you try to exclude the openJFX dependencies from CalendarFX? Like `dependencies {
    implementation ('com.calendarfx:view:11.8.3') { exclude group: 'org.openjfx', module: '' }}`?

Comment: Interesting, that seems to fix it for the "./gradlew run" command, however, when using IntelliJ, right clicking the Main Application file and running it from there, results again in the same error. Is there a way to resolve that?

Comment: That's a very different issue, that has been already covered in other SO questions: Running as Java application from IntelliJ fails to apply the right VM arguments. You should add them to the Run configuration, or use the gradle window to run the proper gradle tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your VM arguments:

```
--module-path \path\to\javafx-sdk\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Answer (score 1):

**JavaFx does not come with CalendarFx ,
Download the lib and import it in your project.**

**https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/CalendarFX/releases/download/11.8.3/view-11.8.3.jar**